# Self product $E \times E$ of an elliptic curve $E$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, abelian-varieties

Suppose that the self product $E \times E$ of an
elliptic curve $E$ contains a compact Riemann surface $C$ of genus $2$.

For points $a, b \in E$, we have to $D = a \times E+E \times b$ is ample divisor in $E\times E$.

My question is: Does anyone see any problem if there is $p$ in $E\times E$ such that $C= D + p$ ?

What is the absurdity if this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: $D + p$ is isomorphic to $D$ as a scheme. In particular, it is the union of two elliptic curves, not a curve of genus 2.

Comment: And why the union of two elliptic curves cannot be a Riemann surface?

Comment: Because it is not smooth (the intersection point $(a,b) + p$ of two components is a node).